Missing Character Error in Latex during Jupyter Notebook to PDF export
I'm attempting to export a Jupyter notebook (in a local instance of JuypterLab) to a PDF. The PDF contains some logical symbols that latex can't find so it giving an error for each of them:
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ∼ (U+223C) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ⊃ (U+2283) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ≡ (U+2261) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ∼ (U+223C) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ∨ (U+2228) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!

I'm assuming that possible solution involve:

installing the fonts
changing the fonts used during the conversion

But I have no idea how to check to see what unicode characters are available in any font family. Nor am I able to figure out how to install the font family that does have the required characters into latex. I'm also confused about whether latex can utilize system fonts on my Mac or whether it needs its own copies.
Any help pointing this latex newb in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks.

If you use an unicode-aware engine like lualatex, you can use system fonts via the fontspec package. To see which fonts have a particular symbol, you could use the command line tool albatross.

Just a little recap, the issue is generated because the default LaTeX font lmroman10-regular does not include the symbols (∧, ∼, ⊃, ≡, ∨).
You can support these symbols by using a LaTeX font package unicode-math, which should support the symbols you are using.
\usepackage{unicode-math}

If you are using markdown cells in the notebook, you can enable this via \(\) LaTeX math environments directly.
If you want to install fonds that include logical symbols, you can install the cm-unicode package for LaTeX.
Another angle to look at is changing how Jupyter converts to a PDF. Within their site, you should be able to customize the LaTeX conversion template by specifying font settings that support your symbols.
You should run the command into your terminal to convert using xelatex which handles unicode better.
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --PDFExporter.latex_command="xelatex" notebook.ipynb

If your issues persist, you should check available fonts and supported unicode characters from the LaTeX Font Catalogue.
Edit:
Jupyter notebooks don't allow you to modify the preamble directly in a notebook cell. However, you should be able to customize the template used by nbconvert.
For that, you need to create a LaTeX template with the required preamble settings and tell nbconvert to use said template.
Just create a directory to store template:
mkdir ~/.jupyter/custom_latex_templates

Inside the directory, create a file named custom.tplx and add the following:
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

((* block header *))
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
((* endblock header *))

Run the nbconvert cmd, specifying the template:
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --template=custom.tplx notebook.ipynb

Next, I would utilize math environments like inline math such as
Inline math: \( \text{your equation here} \)
As $\text{your equation here}$
This wont help directly with the font issue but should assist with math formatting within notebook.
In regards to fixing the xelatex errors, it might not be installed or accessible in your environment. You can just install it via MacTeX as shown:
sudo tlmgr install xetex

After that, run the jupyter nbconvert --to pdf --PDFExporter.latex_command="xelatex" command again.

Thanks for the options here. I (think that I) loaded cm-unicode using: sudo tlmgr install cm-unicode. Still getting the same error though. I also tried putting the use package{unicode-math} command as the top cell in my Jupyter Lab notebook but I'm getting an error that I need to put it in a "preamble", which I'm assuming is a Jupyter configuration file somewhere--? Where would I enable a LaTeX math environment with \(\)? I also tried the Jupyter terminal command you suggested but getting a, Failed to run "['xelatex']" command.

Yeah, updated the question to address issues. If there are any more additional questions or problems, I'll keep stacking them onto the question.
